# Add PhpSpreadsheet Attachment in Email

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to generate a `PhpSpreadsheet` document and then send it as an email attachment.

Here's my file for sending the email:

```php
$name = 'export-sst';
$filename = FileAssociatedPeer::getNewTempFilename($name . '.xlsx"');
$filepath = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . sfConfig::get('app_sfPropelFileAssocPlugin_temp_dir') . '/' . $filename;

include dirname(__FILE__) . 'template.php';

$mail = new PHPMailerBootstrap();
$mail->initialize();
$mail->setCharset('utf-8');
$mail->setContentType('text/html');

$mail->setMailer('smtp');
$mail->setPort((int) sfConfig::get('app_send_mail_port'));
$mail->setHostname(sfConfig::get('app_send_mail_host'));
$mail->setUsername(sfConfig::get('app_send_mail_username'));
$mail->setPassword(sfConfig::get('app_send_mail_password'));
$mail->setSender('cyril@quarks.pro');
$mail->setFrom('cyril@quarks.pro', 'Logiciel Quarks');

$subject = 'test';

$mail->setSubject($subject);
$body = <<<EOT
Test
EOT;
$mail->setBody(nl2br($body));
$mail->addAddress('test@talala.com');

$mail->addAttachment($spreadsheet, $name . '.xlsx', 'base64', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

$mail->send();
```

Here's my PhpSpreadsheet construction after looking documentation:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\{Spreadsheet, IOFactory};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\{Style, Conditional, Alignment, Fill, Border};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\{Worksheet, Drawing};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$active_sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$active_sheet->setTitle('Tableau général');
$active_sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
$active_sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'tada');


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

I have no problem for sending mail without `addAttachement()` but when I uncomment this line, all my attempts throw errors. Thank you for your time

Comment: You are creating a spreadsheet and sending it to the browser. You will need to save it to a file which may then be attached to the mail you are sending.

Comment: I try lot of think. like 
``` $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save($filepath); ``` and  
  ```      $mail->addAttachment($filepath, $name . '.xlsx', 'base64', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```
I have another error Could not close zip file /var/...tmp1563982511-8751#export-sst.xlsx"

Comment: You're on the right track, but it sounds like you have other issues you need to solve with generating the spreadsheet as either a file or a string before you get as far as attaching it to an email - solve the first problem first!

Comment: After few new try i have a new error.
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started 
I have try to make my document just with download and i have no problem

Comment: It's work. I fix my issue with right permission in tmp folder. Thank guys for your help

Comment: @Cyril, since you solved your own problem, you should post your solution as an answer to your question, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The couldn't close  zip file error indicates that you have not the right permissions for the target file path.

Try to use the absolut path to be sure you have the right path.

```
$path = "<Absolut Path>";

//do stuff

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save($path);
```

Comment: My path was good. I solve my problem with right permission in my folder. Thank for your time. Have a nice day